# How do I replace the default fonts and their minimum font sizes in Safari?

Tags: mac, safari, macos

I'm using Safari 10.0 on macOS Sierra.
I want to replace all the four default fonts in Safari - **standard, fixed, serif and sans-serif**.
I've tried looking for a .plist file that contains the information of the default fonts but haven't found it yet.
Please help.